# Triger after update como solução para debitar creditos de forma segura

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, doctrine, trigger

Preciso fazer uma interface que garanta a integridade dos creditos do cliente.
No PHP, quando usamos LOCK de forma explicita no PDO, com LOCK TABLES, se tratando pode haver inconsistencia, quando o mesmo objeto cliente, estiver em vários processos relacionandos mesmo que de forma indireta à ação de debitar creditos.
Por outro lado, o LOCK implicito, usando uma TRIGGER, pode ser mais seguro.
Deixar o banco fazer o serviço.
É possível numa trigger After Update, depois de atualizar os creditos da tabela creditos, fazer uma operação para verificar se os creditos são negativos, e no vaso de ser, então fazer um rolback da transação.
Se é possível, qual a melhor forma de fazer.
Pensei em fazer a operação dentro de um block try catch e pegar a exception.
Alguém me ajuda com essa analogia, Obrigado

Comment: Não é possivel fazer isso na trigger.

Comment: Qual seria a melhor forma de fazer isso ?
Eu quero descontar os créditos.
Se o crédito resultante for menor que 0, então quero fazer o rollback dessa transação, e então, na camada da aplicação, eu trato o erro.

Comment: Faz uma procedure. Passe os parametros a ela e ela poderá comitar ou fazer o rollback em função das regras do negócio.

Comment: e eu consigo fazer um look dentro dessa procedure Reginaldo Rigo ?

Comment: Sim. Você poderá fazer praticamente qualquer coisa.